# How do I select DOM elements in Chrome Dev Tools by clicking on them in document?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

For example I have clicked a button and it has been selected in inspector. I don't fire any events on this button if inspector is opened. Just select elements I want simply clicking on them in document. This is how dragonfly works in opera. I wish to use chrome for all purposes but inspecting DOM is tiring for me without this feature. Or maybe i have missed it in settings?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In inpector window in top-left corner we have loupe button. Just press it and them on DOM element on page.